# Adding logo to a custom theme as background image

Tags: 8, theming

I have a custom Drupal 8 theme that I'm working on. A requirement is that the client logo for this custom theme be a background image on an HTML object. I also need to add script that swaps the background image used between two different images depending on the background of the rest of the page.

Where do I add these CSS styles and the JavaScript code in Drupal 8 custom theme files?

Answer (score -1):

Your custom theme will live in the folder themes/yourtheme

Inside your theme you can have a js and css directory and you can add your css/js files in those folders.

Inside your libraries.yourtheme.yaml file you can declare your library files

```
base:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
```

Inside yourtheme.info.yaml file you can call your declared libraries if you want them to load on every page:

```
libraries:
  - yourtheme/base
```

If you want the libraries to only load in some pages they can be called in the twig template files using the attach_library() function:

```
{{ attach_library('yourtheme/base') }}
```

More in depth documentation can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)